# Convert async loop to LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

I have this straightforward loop that I'd like to write declaratively, using LINQ.

```
    async Task<Foo> GetFooAsync(string fooId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        foreach (var source in FooSources)
        {
            var result = await source.GetFooAsync(fooId, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I wish for something that looks like:

```
return FooSources.Where(...).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm stuck, especially on making LINQ and `async`/`await` work together.

Comment: You can use async in a lambda, too :)

Comment: install resharper and you can convert such loops to a lambda expression

Comment: @FabianBigler: Show us what that would look like, in an answer.

Answer (score 13):

Your options for `async` LINQ are very limited. As the other answer pointed out, you can use async methods in `Select`, but that's about it:

```
var tasks = FooSources.Select(source => source.GetFooAsync(fooId, cancellationToken));
```

This will get you a sequence of `Task<Foo>`. You can then await for them all to complete:

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Now you have an array of `Foo`, which can be filtered:

```
return results.Where(foo => foo != null);
```

Note that this has very different semantics than your original code. Your original code will `await` each source before starting the next; this answer will start all sources going, and then `await` them all.

If you want `foreach` semantics and need to `await` inside the loop, then the correct solution is to use a `foreach` loop containing an `await`. There is no direct LINQ equivalent.